# Not getting right output if i execute command via ssh

Tags: linux, unix

The output of the following command

```
sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +100000 -name "*.log" -exec gzip -v {} \; 2>&1 | awk '{print $6}'
```

give me

```
/opt/testing3/cat1.log.gz
/opt/testing3/cat2.log.gz
/opt/testing3/cat3.log.gz
/opt/testing3/cat4.log.gz
/opt/testing3/cat5.log.gz
/opt/testing3/cat6.log.gz
/opt/testing3/cat7.log.gz
```

However If I do it via ssh it gives me:

```
 ssh user@hostname "sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +100000 -name \"*.log\" -exec gzip -v {} \; 2>&1 | awk '{print $6}'"
```

results in

```
/opt/testing3/cat1.log:  95.4% -- replaced with /opt/testing3/cat1.log.gz
/opt/testing3/cat2.log:  95.4% -- replaced with /opt/testing3/cat2.log.gz
/opt/testing3/cat3.log:  95.4% -- replaced with /opt/testing3/cat3.log.gz
/opt/testing3/cat4.log:  95.4% -- replaced with /opt/testing3/cat4.log.gz
/opt/testing3/cat5.log:  95.4% -- replaced with /opt/testing3/cat5.log.gz
/opt/testing3/cat6.log:  95.4% -- replaced with /opt/testing3/cat6.log.gz
/opt/testing3/cat7.log:  95.4% -- replaced with /opt/testing3/cat7.log.gz
```

Why is the output different? It seems that the awk does not get executed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape "$" symbol, in order not to get it locally, but to pass remotely.

```
$ ssh $HOSTNAME "ls -l /tmp | tail -1 | awk '{print $6}'"
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       0 Apr 29 01:31 file.log
$ ssh $HOSTNAME "ls -l /tmp | tail -1 | awk '{print \$6}'"
Apr
```